# I need to save a value from a map on database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

Well, I need help to save a value from const map in data base.
I have search on some forums, read the MongoDB docs but i found nothing, so, how I can save with for a value from a map (individually) on mongodb?

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Members = require('../models/Members');
const { DATABASE } = require('../../config/config.json');

module.exports.run = async (Client, message, args) => {
  const ServerCache = Client.guilds.cache.get('719394166483845210');

  const cacheID = ServerCache.members.cache.map(member => member.user.id);
  const cacheTag = ServerCache.members.cache.map(member => member.user.tag);
  const cacheIsBot = ServerCache.members.cache.map(member => member.user.bot);

  // Database connection
  mongoose.connect(DATABASE.URL, DATABASE.OPTIONS);

  for (var i = 0; i < cacheID.length; i++) {
    if (cacheIsBot[i]) {
      console.log("Este usuário é um BOT, então foi ignorado!");
    } else {

      Members.find({ 'dsID': cacheID[i] }, (err, discordID) => {
        if (discordID.length >= 1) {
          console.log("Este usuário já está cadastrado");
          return;
        }

        const MembersDocument = new Members({
          dsID: cacheID[i],
          dsTag: cacheTag[i]
        });

        MembersDocument.save();
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did with other way, adding a new variables to refer the map item:

```js
const dsID = cacheID[i];
const dsTag = cacheTag[i];
```

And on the new document

```js
const MembersDocument = new Members({
    dsID: dsID,
    dsTag: dsTag,
});
```

Works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an async function in the for loop. So the loop ends before the function respond. You can use async module for this.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Members = require('../models/Members');
const async = require("async");
const { DATABASE } = require('../../config/config.json');

module.exports.run = async (Client, message, args) => {
  const ServerCache = Client.guilds.cache.get('719394166483845210');

  const dsID = ServerCache.members.cache.map(member => member.user.id);
  const dsTag = ServerCache.members.cache.map(member => member.user.tag);
  const dsIsBot = ServerCache.members.cache.map(member => member.user.bot);

  // Database connection
  mongoose.connect(DATABASE.URL, DATABASE.OPTIONS);

  async.eachSeries(dsID, function (dsIDItem, nextItem) {
      let i = dsID.indexOf(dsIDItem); // for dsTag and dsIsBot index.
      if (dsIsBot[i]) {
      console.log("Este usuário é um BOT, então foi ignorado!")
    } else {
      Members.find({ 'dsID': dsIDItem }, (err, discordID) => {
        if (discordID.length >= 1) { return; }

        const MembersDocument = new Members({
          dsID: dsIDItem, // <-- I tried to use [i] to save that map value with for
          dsTag: dsTag[i],
        });

        MembersDocument.save(function(){ nextItem(); });
      });
    }
  }, function(err) {
      // end loop
  })
}
```